# ¿Cómo puedo buscar dentro de modelos anidados desde una vista separada en rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo 2 modelos anidados

- Clients
- Packages

y una vista llamada **Dashboard** lo que quiero hacer es implementar un buscador que desde **Dashboard** busque dentro de **Clients** o **Packages** y me devuelva el resultado de la búsqueda en la vista **Dashboard**.

¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

**Modelos:**

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :packages, dependent: :destroy
end

class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

**Parcial en "Dashboard":**

```
<!-- Search Form -->
<div class="row search">
  <div class="col-xs-12 pull-right">
    <%= form_tag dashboard_index_path, :method => "get" do %>
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search package barcodes" %>
    </p>
    <p class="pull-right">
      <%= submit_tag "Search", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
    </p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ./Search -->
```

**Rutas:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'dashboard#index'
  get 'dashboard/index'

  devise_for :users
  resources :clients do
    resources :packages
  end

end
```

**Rake routes:**

[image: rake routes]

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma fácil seria crear un método nuevo find_by_string (por ejemplo) en el modelo Clients el cual busque por clientes y posteriormente por paquetes, guardando todos estos resultados en un Arreglo el cual puede ser iterado en tu vista y consultando el tipo del objeto podrías diferenciarlos para fines de estilo.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  def find_by_string(query)
    results = Array.new
    Client.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%").map{ |client| results << client}
    Client.all.map{|client| client.packages.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{query}%").map {|package| results << package}}
    return result
  end

end
```